# What is wrong with this Fermat's last theorem proof?

Tags: number-theory

I wanted to mess around with Fermat's last theorem, I would like to share my (very basic) try:

Let: $$0 < x, y < z \in \mathbb{N} ~~ \text{and} ~~ n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 2$$

Assuming it is true that $$x^n + y^n = z^n$$

Can we can say it is true for any $\alpha > 0$ ? : $$x^{n+ \alpha} + y^{n+ \alpha} = z^{n+\alpha}$$

If it is true, then: $$x^{\alpha} \cdot x^n + y^{\alpha} \cdot y^n = z^{\alpha} \cdot (x^n + y^n)$$  because we substituted $x^n + y^n = z^n$

Then:
$$x^n (x^{\alpha}-z^{\alpha}) = y^n (z^{\alpha}-y^{\alpha})$$
Is true for all $0 < x, y < z \in \mathbb{N} ~~ \text{and} ~~ n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

It can't be true, as the left side, which is $x^n (x^{\alpha}-z^{\alpha})$ is a negative number ($x^{\alpha}<z^{\alpha}$)  while the right side is always positive ($z^{\alpha}>y^{\alpha}$) thus it is a contradiction to the assumption.

This is only works when $\alpha = 0$ but contradicts any positive number afterwards, taking $n=3$ and we can contradict the assumption for $n=4,5,6, \dots$

What is the problem here? I mean, you can theoretically take $n=1$ but it is true that $x+y=z$ has infinite solutions, but that can be dealt with alone by proving there is at least one solution.

Comment: The problem is that "I will try to explain later... If it is true, then" does not constitute a proof, and the answer to "Can we say it is true?" Is "No we cannot"

Comment: @MorganRodgers I edited this post and forgot to remove that line, sorry I will edit

Comment: It doesn't really change the fact that the crucial detail you want for your proof is not proven, and is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assuming it is true that $$x^n + y^n = z^n$$  Can we can say it is true for any $\alpha > 0$ ? : $$x^{n+ \alpha} + y^{n+ \alpha} = z^{n+\alpha}$$

Certainly not. It might help to consider $\alpha=n$. Then we have $$x^n+y^n=z^n\implies (x^n+y^n)(x^n+y^n)=z^{n+n},$$ but $$(x^n+y^n)^2=x^{n+n}+y^{n+n}\color{red}{+2x^ny^n},$$ which is very different from $x^{n+n}+y^{n+n}$ per the red bit.

In fact, the above shows that if $x^n+y^n=z^n$ and $x,y\not=0$ then we **never** have $x^{2n}+y^{2n}=z^{2n}$. So exponents don't work the way you would need them to for this argument.

Comment: But that is what we wanted in the first place no? As $\alpha$ can be any number, then if let's say we take $n=k$ and $\alpha = 1, 2, \dots$ it won't be true then the whole statement that there exist $x,y,z$ such that $x^k + y^k = z^k$ is false

Comment: @OnAndOff No - a putative counterexample to Fermat for one value of $n$ has no reason to be (in fact, will not) be a counterexample for some other value of $n$. It may help to note that Fermat's last theorem is **false** if we allow $x,y,z$ to be *real* numbers. So whatever reason you have for believing Fermat, it has to be somehow special to the integers - it can't be just general properties of exponents.

Comment: For example, we have $$1^3+1^3=(\sqrt[3]{2})^3,$$ but $$1^4+1^4\not=(\sqrt[3]{2})^4.$$ So you can actually observe failures of this kind of exponent-juggling.

Comment: Noah Schweber:  Please consider running in the upcoming election for a new moderator.  I think you would make an excellent candidate, and an excellent moderator!